# Change debug-setting based on port-number?

Tags: django

Sorry for this silly question. I am quite new to django.

Can I set DEBUG=False or DEBUG=True in settings.py or from commandline **if the application runs from a specific port-number** ?

If so, how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by passing a settings module to the command like this:

```
python manage.py runserver --settings=mysettings
```

and in your `mysettings.py` you could import the actual settings file and then overwrite whatever you need.

```
#mysettings.py

from myproject.settings import *
DEBUG = False
```

Comment: can I set port and address via settings too ?

Comment: You can set the address and the port as the first argument.

`python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 --settings=mysettings`